Tate's thesis paper
Where I can read a full version of Tate’s thesis Fourier Analysis in Number Fields and Hecke’s Zetafunctions 1950?
Someone told me that it is written in the Cassels-Frolich Algebraic number theory Chapter 15 but I don't think it is full because of 43 pages only.
Can you please give a link?

The complete thesis is in Cassels and Frolich.  If you are unsatisfied with that, and you have access to ProQuest, you can get the original thesis that way: https://faq.library.princeton.edu/special-collections/faq/11166 .

That what is in Cassels-Frohlich is $43$ pages might make it seem short to you, but there is a footnote at the bottom of the first page saying it is an "unaltered reproduction of Tate's doctoral thesis". The only difference is that what is seen in C-F is surely typeset much more nicely than the original version submitted to Princeton.
Edit: On the topic of short PhD theses in math, see here.

Ok. Thank you! The question was about a small number of pages.

@094712 Theses in mathematics tend to be short.  Most of my friends and colleagues find mine to be ridiculously verbose at 120ish pages.  Most PhD theses that I've seen weigh in at around 50--60 pages.  40ish pages is on the shorter end of the spectrum, but not really an outlier in any way.  It may be worth remembering that a lot of mathematicians fetishize brevity. :D

Thank you! In my short mathematical life I have seen only 70+ pages in PhD thesis. But this is taking into account the introduction and reminders
